# delete a particular row on clicking the edit link in magento

Tags: magento

i created a edit link and want to edit the row content and save the changes to database using magento. i created the delete link it works properly

```
if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('class') > 0 ) {


    try {
        $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');

        $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('class'))
        ->setTitle('new title')->setUpdateTime(strtotime('now'))->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully edited'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear please elaborate.

Comment: Can you please show any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete row then add below action in the controller hope this helps.

```
public function deleteAction() {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('class') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');

                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('class'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());

            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

Comment: But your question says "delete a particular row on clicking the edit link in magento"

Comment: Change strtotime('now') to now() test this code
$model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('class'))
        ->setTitle('new title')->setUpdateTime(now())->save();